# magento 2 Cant show products on categories

Tags: magento2, category, products

I have added some products in one category. All products are enabled, with quantity and catalog, search option, I have also disabled cache and reindexed multiple times but on the frontend the product will show only if I directly access the products url and they do not show up on the category page.

Comment: If you can see category page and can view products and catalog,search option is selected then only other suggestion would be reindexing data and making sure cache is cleared but as you say you've already done it and didn't help, you can try creating a new category and a new simple product for that category to see if that could help.

Comment: Is 'Enable product' set to 'yes'? Is 'stock status' 'in stock'? Are these products simples? Compound products have availability requirements for their associated products. Does 'Product in Websites' have the correct website selected? Have these settings been made to the correct store view (drop down list at the top)?

Comment: Enable product = yes, stock status = in stock
all products are simple and Product in Websites have the main website (only one store there), i even tried to create a new category and put a product in that category and again same thing is happening!!
I can only see the product only if i directly access the products url

Comment: Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: @nada, kindly share your category page in admin

Answer (score 0):

When you create a subcategory, make sure you set the "Display Mode" like in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Some reason after an upgrade from 2.0.1 to 2.1.1 the problem seems that solved by itself!

Answer (score 0):

Run below query in mysql.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_text where store_id != 0;
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_datetime where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_int where store_id != 0; 
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar where store_id != 0;
```